# How to load page content by URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was asked during an interview to write a piece of code to highlight the url if the content of the url contains a certain keyword. I honestly do not know how I can do that with JavaScript...

Comment: Do you mean if the page at the URL contains a keyword?  Or the URL itself contains the keyword?

Comment: Make an Ajax call to the url? Look for the string in the returned current? Which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: What blocks my mind was "how to load a page content from the url using JavaScript"... never done that, I mean, who does this? Anyways, looks like it is doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can firstly fetch content using ajax, search for keyword,
then highlight the url if necessary.
But this comes with limitation:

1. The url you want to highlight should allow cross-site ajax fetching.
2. performance will not be so good, since you need to fetch each url if there are many.
3. If the targeting url is client-side rendering, fetching its html simply won't see the content since its not render yet.

Normally we won't solve this using front-end approach, but using search-engine indexing method instead.

Comment: I agree that it is not a normally a front-end task, but let's assume it has to be, how would you do it if there are 1000 urls?

Comment: If so, in virtual you should visit all 1000 urls so you can check if the keyword in the content.
I'll using jQuery.ajax (or other ajax approach) to fetch all contents. 
Then using regular expression to check if keyword exists.

If so, add a style on the anchor so you can style it.

Again, this will be very, very slow.

Comment: This is the naive approach, I'm looking for a better/more scalable way